# foreach loop in sync function in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have code written

```
function getDetails (req, res) {
    const dbQuery = `call spGetSLAReportsDetails('${req.body.domainId}', ${req.body.days},'${req.body.type}','${req.body.app}')`
    try {
      connectDatabase(dbQuery).then((rows) => {
        if (!_.isEmpty(rows.dbData) && !_.isEmpty(rows.dbData[0])) {
          const resultList = []
          rows.dbData.pop()
          var bar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            rows.dbData[0].forEach((element, index, array) => {
              let query = `select * from YCW.YWFWIC  ic where ic.witem=${element.witem} and ic.reqno=${element.reqno};`
                connectDatabase(query).then((data) =>{
                  for (var i = 0; i < data.dbData.length; i++) {
                    element[data.dbData[i]["cfield"]] = data.dbData[i]["cvalue"]
                }
                resultList.push(element)
                // console.log(resultList)
                }).catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err)
                })
                if (index === array.length -1) resolve();
            });
        });

        bar.then(() => {
          console.log(resultList);
      });
          res.status(msgCodeJson.ERR004.code).send({
            result: resultList })
        } else {
          console.log("empty array")
          res.status(msgCodeJson.ERR004.code).send({
            message : "No data found"
          })
          // httpResponseHandlerError(res, msgCodeJson.ERR001.code, msgCodeJson.ERR001.msg)
        }
      }).catch(() => {
        httpResponseHandlerError(res, msgCodeJson.ERR002.code, msgCodeJson.ERR002.msg)
      })
    } catch (err) {
      httpResponseHandlerError(res, msgCodeJson.ERR009.code, msgCodeJson.ERR009.msg)
    }
  }

  module.exports.getDetails = getDetails
```

i want data to be fit in resultlist but i get empty list after all operation.
while in foreach loop i am getting proper output.
kindly help in issue.
i tried with async foreach loop but some syntax error is coming.
kindly help

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in the comment of the code you're using
[Best way to wait for .forEach() to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406920/best-way-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete)

> This is OK if there is no async processing inside the loop.

yet you have an async function inside your forEach callback, namly this:

```
connectDatabase(query).then((data) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.dbData.length; i++) {
        element[data.dbData[i]["cfield"]] = data.dbData[i]["cvalue"]
    }
    resultList.push(element)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

you'll need to resolve the "outer/parent" promise from inside the "inner/child" promise

---

I suggest using a regular good old `for` loop and/or checking the count of resolved promises against the `rows.dbData[0].length` and calling a final code/function once they match