# Wait for append data to complete in .each()

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a set of inputs and images:

[image]

I am looping through the `divs` to get the names and the photos:

```
$('.subCats').each(function () {
    let id   = genRandomStr(),
        name = $(this).find('input.subCatName').val();

    if (name.length > 0) {
        dataObj['subCats'].push({
            'id'   : id,
            'name' : $(this).find('input.subCatName').val()
        });

        $(this).find('.media-list img').each(function () {
            if ($(this).data('stored') === false)
                urlToFile($(this).attr('src'), $(this).attr('title'), 'image')
                    .then(function (file) {
                        data.append('subCatsPhotos[' + id + ']', file);
                });
        });
    }

});
```

I have an AJAX request just after but the problem is the request is executing before the image has been appended to the `FormData`.

This is the code that is converting the image to a file object:

```
function urlToFile(url, filename, mimeType) {
    return (fetch(url)
        .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
        .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], filename,{type:mimeType});})
);
```

}

I have looked at [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406920/best-way-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete) but I am struggling to adapt them to my code.

Comment: what is `urlToFile`?

Comment: `Image().onload = ()=>{ // append}`

Comment: @epascarello a function that is converting the image to file object

Comment: @Jolan how it is implemented will determine the solution....

Comment: @epascarello I have added the code to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep track of how many appends have happened:

```js
let appended = 0;
const elements = [1,2,3,4,5];
elements.forEach(element => {
    // Do whatever with element
    // Using setTimeout to emulate .then()
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Appended', element, 'at', Date.now());
        if (++appended === elements.length) {
            console.log('Appended all!');
            // Do your AJAX request
        }
    }, 100 * Math.random());
});
```

Alternatively, if you can use .map instead of .each:

```js
const elements = [5,4,8,7,5,4];
const promise = Promise.all(elements.map(element => {
    // Some promise
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Appended', element, 'at', Date.now());
        r();
    }, Math.random() * 100));
}));
promise.then(() => {
    console.log('Appended all!');
});
```