# variable changes inside forEach not saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have these lines here

```
let users = []
members.forEach(member => {
  let profile

  db.get(member.id).then(value => {
    profile = JSON.parse(value)
  })

  if(profile == null)
    return

  if(profile.bank + profile.cash > 0)
  {
    let user = new User(member, profile)
    users.push(user)
  }
})
console.log(users)
```

I want to save User objects into the users array, but outside the forEach loop, it is undefined.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Because it is ASYNCHRONOUS. The code after the callback does not magically sit there and wait for it to be called.

Comment: `db.get(member.id).then(value => {
    console.log("callback", member.id);
    profile = JSON.parse(value)
  });     console.log("after", member.id);`

Comment: Here's a [visualizer](http://latentflip.com/loupe/) represent what @epascarello mentioned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to wait for .forEach() to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406920/best-way-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete)

Comment: I've tried the solution from Douglas Rosebank but it still doesn't work. @Hogan

Comment: @Dave -- interesting .. what exactly did you try and what exactly did it do?

Comment: What is `db.get`? What library?

Answer (score 2):

You problem is how javascript works --

```
 (member =>
```

represents a function call.  But that function may not be finished by the time you get to your console log.  You need a promise to make sure it is done.

[Best way to wait for .forEach() to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406920/best-way-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete)